# Selecting listed fields from the django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have went through this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-fields
but my requirement is different.

I have a store model with custom mangers:

```
class VegManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(VegManager, self).get_query_set().filter(plus=True)

class FruitsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(FruitsManager, self).get_query_set().filter(plus=True)


class SweetsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(SweetsManager, self).get_query_set().filter(plus=True)


    class Store(models.Model):
        vegetable = models.BooleanField()
        veg1_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
        veg2_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
        veg3_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
        fruits = models.BoolearnField()
        fruit1_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
        fruit2_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
        fruit3_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
        sweets = models.BooleanField()
        sweet1_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
        sweet2_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
        sweet3_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
        objects = models.Manager()
        v = VegManager()
        f = FruitsManager()
        s = SweetsManager()

    class Veg(Store):
        class Meta:
            proxy = True

    class  Froots(Store):
        class Meta:
            proxy = True

    class Sweet(Store):
        class Meta:
            proxy = True
```

Is there any way that if i do `sweets.v.all()` and it gives me only the price of vegetables? Instead of getting all the price data for sweets and fruits as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#defer-fields

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be filtering your managers by `vegetable`, `fruits` and `sweets` boolean fields instead of `plus`, which is a field I don't even see in your model?

```
class VegManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(VegManager, self).get_query_set().filter(vegetables=True)

class FruitsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(FruitsManager, self).get_query_set().filter(fruits=True)

class SweetsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(SweetsManager, self).get_query_set().filter(sweets=True)
```